# Difficulty in understanding a derivation : Asymptotic behaviour of binomial coeeficients

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

[image]

I don't understand how we get the second line from the first line in the above image. Here $k = \delta \frac{d}{t}$ where $\delta$ is some very small constant greater than $0$. Also $N = d^3$.

So, last line is basically $2^{\Omega( \frac{d}{t}\log d)}$.

From the following expression
 $$
\frac{1}{2^{O(d/t)}} \operatorname{min}( {d \choose k}^2.d^k.k!.e^{(-kt)\ln\frac{1+ (k/d) \ln d}{1 - (k/d)\ln d}}, e^{(d-k-kt)\ln\frac{1+ (k/d) \ln d}{1 - (k/d) \ln d}}) $$

I can get

$$
\frac{1}{2^{O(d/t)}} e^{(-kt)\ln\frac{1+ (k/d) \ln d}{1 - (k/d)\ln d}} \operatorname{min}( {d \choose k}^2.d^k.k!., e^{(d-k)}) $$

But I don't understand how the above expression will give us $2^{\Omega(d/t \log d)}$

Comment: More context and MathJax would help.